# How to update multiple rows in same Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "tbl_settings".

I have 4 columns: id, name, value, description.

I have an html form listing a text box for each setting.

Upon submit,  I want to update each setting value based on the name of the setting.

For reference, my setting names for a few rows are :
site_title, site_title_description, contact_name.

I need help figuring out the best method to update all of the rows with the respective value based on the name of the row.

I am writing this on my phone and don't currently have code with me, so please just a general idea on the query I need to run .

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: What have you tried?  Generally, for any given individual update (any unique combination of (1) identifiers for the rows to target and (2) values to set in those rows), you'd issue an `UPDATE` command to the database.

Comment: An update with a where clause for the text match would do it. `update table set name = 'new site title' where name = 'site_title'` every row with the `name` as `site_title` would be reset to `new site title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_settings
SET value = 'new title'
WHERE name = 'site_title'
```

This will change all the `site_title` rows to have `value = 'new title'`.

The `WHERE` clause can use any of the same conditions that you would use in a `SELECT` query to view the rows you want to update.

If you want to assign differentt values based on some other condition, you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE tbl_settings
SET value = CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN 'new title 1'
    WHEN condition2 THEN 'new title 2'
    WHEN condition3 THEN 'new title 3'
END
WHERE name = 'site_title'
AND (condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3)
```

Or maybe this is what you want:

```
UPDATE tbl_settings
SET value = CASE name
    WHEN 'site_title' THEN 'new title'
    WHEN 'site_title_description' THEN 'new description'
    WHEN 'contact_name' THEN 'new contact name'
END
WHERE name in ('site_title', 'site_title_description', 'contact_name')
```

Comment: I need to update MULTIPLE rows with DIFFERENT values.

Comment: You should explain it more clearly in the question. How do you determine which rows to update with which values?

Comment: My apologies.  I am posting from my phone and am away from the computer right now.  I have tried the case feature to update each row but that does not work.

Comment: Come back when you're on a real computer so you can work productively.

Comment: You need to edit the question to show clearly what you're trying to accomplish. Show the original table contents, and what you're trying to change it to based on the form.

Comment: This is exactly what  I needed.  The last section of code worked for me.

My apologies on the vague question, but I really appreciate your knowledge and help.  Marked this as the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: I wish I could have up voted this 10x! I never knew this was possible! (I am pertaining to the top most solution)